# Python bottle runs initialization method twice

Tags: python, web-applications, bottle

I've got a problem with bottle, the `_initialize` function is run twice. Example app:

```
 @route("/index")
 def index():
      return "bang"

 def _initialize():
      print("bam")

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     _initialize()
     run(reloader=True, host="localhost", port = 8990)
```

The output is:

```
bam
bam
Bottle v0.11.rc1 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...                             
Listening on http://localhost:8080/                                                        
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
```

Why is it happening and how can I do such pre init in bottle?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is the `reloader=True` argument for the `run` function. See http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#auto-reloading for the sentence:

> All module-level code is executed at least twice! Be careful.