# Why doesn't bottlepy server load?

Tags: python, webserver, wsgi, bottle, wsgiref

I am confused as to why the bottlepy server doesn't run:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = datetime.now()
    db = Database(force_refresh_cache=False,
                  timestamp_filename='timestamp.pickle',
                  schema_filename='schema.pickle')
    print datetime.now(), 'Took:', (datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()

    run(host='localhost', port=80, reloader=True, debug=True)
```

When I comment out the db construction; the server runs.

In both cases I get the timestamped "Took: [seconds]" line, which implies that no error occurred earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the module level code, and potentially the fact that you are using the reloader switch. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064490/python-bottle-runs-initialization-method-twice) out.

All module level code is run at least twice when the reloader is on. I haven't tested this, but this would make sense as it wouldn't be able to spawn a child if the DB were already tied up.

try this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = datetime.now()
    db = Database(force_refresh_cache=False,
                  timestamp_filename='timestamp.pickle',
                  schema_filename='schema.pickle')
    print datetime.now(), 'Took:', (datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()

    run(host='localhost', port=80, debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, now tempted to write a function to ensure the database is always constructed for each of the endpoints… unfortunately I would need to decorate every endpoint with this. Is there an alternative, if I want: `reloader=True`?

Comment: I find the functionality of the reloader to be pretty buggy anyhow. You could add a persistent file that indicates whether or not the DB has been loaded, to ensure only one instance is loaded, but I can't think of anything else off the top of my head.